# Why don't I get stackoverflow exception in overriding and calling virtual function?

Tags: c#, overriding, stack-overflow, virtual-functions

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B foo = new B();
        foo.DoWork();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class A
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}
public class B : A
{
    public override void DoWork() { base.DoWork();  Console.WriteLine("B"); }
}
```

Why don't I get StackOverflow exception? As I understand it, foo.DoWork() is called, then it calls base.DoWork(), which is virtual and overriden in class B.DoWork() method, which would repeat calling base.DoWork() again until stack is overflown. This overflow is easily achieved when using this instead of base (circular loop of calling self). What does prevent virtual function overriding in this case?

Comment: If that's how `base` worked, then anytime it is ever used it would be a stackoverflow, and there would be no reason to have it in the language at all.

Comment: @Servy No, you could call non-virtual methods using base without any problems. This is just a particular case of using base with virtual methods.

Comment: If you want to call a base class's non-virtual method just cast `this` to the base class and call the method.  `base` is literally designed specifically to call the base class's version of a virtual method because it can't be done without `base`, any other use of `base` can be done without that keyword.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, when you use `base` it *doesn't* make a virtual call. The whole point is to be able to call the `base` implementation *even if you've overridden it*.

If you look in the generated IL, you'll see it doesn't use `callvirt`:

```
IL_0002:  call       instance void A::DoWork()
```

From section 7.6.8 of the C# 5 specification (emphasis mine):

> When a base-access references a virtual function member (a method, property, or indexer), the determination of which function member to invoke at run-time (§7.5.4) is changed. **The function member that is invoked is determined by finding the most derived implementation (§10.6.3) of the function member with respect to B (instead of with respect to the run-time type of this, as would be usual in a non-base access).** Thus, within an override of a virtual function member, a base-access can be used to invoke the inherited implementation of the function member. If the function member referenced by a base-access is abstract, a binding-time error occurs.

Comment: [Eric Lippert wrote](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/29/putting-a-base-in-the-middle.aspx) about consequences of the fact that C# goes and finds the most derived base class that actually has an implementation, instead of the direct base class.

Comment: @BenVoigt: (I see we found it at almost exactly the same time :)

Comment: Yep.  I just thought that discussion seemed relevant to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

`A.DoWork` is virtual.  But a method named by `base.` is *never* virtual.  That syntax generates a non-virtual call, so the exact method is called, not the most derived version.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual method is just a method that can be overriden and that contains code. When you call `base.DoWork()` you explicitly state  that you want to call `A.DoWork()`. Then, `A.DoWork()` is called.

Try making `A.DoWork()` abstract then it can't contain code. Then, you will have an compilation error on `base.DoWork()` because there is nothing to execute in `base.DoWork()`.

Comment: overloaded != overridden. You mean overridden here.